# Android / Java Development - Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: java, android, view, scroll

I am wondering how to make multiple horizontal scroll views in one xml file.
Is this a simple adjustment from a normal Scroll View or is this a lot more complex?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes you should be able to put multiple scroll views in on xml. You can try something like:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutRight" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:background="#000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"> 
</HorizontalScrollView>
 <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:background="#f00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp">
  </HorizontalScrollView>  
</LinearLayout>
```